# How to get database credentials

Tags: 7, database

I am integrating code that implements its own extension of PHP's [PDO class](http://php.net/pdo), in the same way that Drupal's [DatabaseConnection](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/class/DatabaseConnection/7) does. So this code (which is various data models) needs to use this non-drupal PDO object.

This code needs DSN, username and password to access the default drupal database. I noted that `$databases`, defined in `settings.php` is not available: `global $databases` does not work to give me access to that data.

Is there a way to ask Drupal for this info or extract it from the default connection object?

Comment: I've posted an initial answer, but how are you you *integrating* this script?  Through a module?  A separate PHP file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following works perfectly for me in *devel/php*

```
global $databases;

dpm($databases);
```

It should return the full array of database information:

[image: databases output]

Comment: My bad, must have been doing something stupid, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As shown by Chapabu `global $databases` does work but it wont work if you are using a separate PHP file (not related to Drupal Codebase), if you want to use it like that you need to `include settings.php` file before.